# Lua table pairs output showing same value

Tags: lua, fivem

im fairly new to lua and working on CFX FiveM, and have made a simple table.insert which calls on a `for type, value in pairs(Config.Skills) do` This is then refering back to a SQL table which is pulling the data correctly, but the table inserts are showing the same value.

SQL OUTPUT - `{"stamina":{"RemoveAmount":-0.3,"Stat":"MP0_STAMINA","Current":25},"strength":{"RemoveAmount":-0.3,"Current":13,"Stat":"MP0_STRENGTH"}}`

Lua Code

```
function SkillMenu()
    FetchSkills()
    Wait(1000)
    RefreshSkills()
    local elements = {}
    for type, value in pairs(Config.Skills) do
        table.insert(elements, {
            type = 'button',
            name = "stamina",
            label = "Stamina",
            description = type .. value["Current"] .. "%",
            icon = 'fad fa-heartbeat',
            disabled = true
        })
        table.insert(elements, {
            type = 'button',
            name = 'strength',
            label = "Strength",
            description = type .. value["Current"] .. "%",
            icon = 'fad fa-heartbeat',
            disabled = true
        })
        TMC.Functions.OpenMenu({
            namespace = "skillmenu",
            type = 'openMenu',
            title = "Skill menu",
        }, elements, function(close, confirmed)
        end, function(selected)
        end, function(change)
            if change.elementChanged == "stamina" then
                TMC.Functions.CloseMenu()
            elseif change.elementChanged == 'strength' then
                TMC.Functions.CloseMenu()
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

[What it is outputting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg2Ae.png)

What I am looking to achieve:

Stamina
stamina25%

Strength
strength13%

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing both `table.insert`s in both iterations, but you should only be creating each menu item once. Either wrap your `table.insert`s in `if` statements so they only run for the correct iteration, or just remove the loop altogether and use expressions like `Config.Skills.stamina.Current` and `Config.Skills.strength.Current` to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

A pairs-loop in Lua means "repeat this action for every item in a table".
So, you should have one `table.insert` in the loop.
You should also remove `OpenMenu` invocation from the loop.

```
local function initcaps(s)
    return s:sub(1,1):upper()..s:sub(2)
end

function SkillMenu()
    FetchSkills()
    Wait(1000)
    RefreshSkills()
    local elements = {}
    for type, value in pairs(Config.Skills) do
        table.insert(elements, {
            type = 'button',
            name = type,
            label = initcaps(type),
            description = type .. " " .. value.Current .. "%",
            icon = 'fad fa-heartbeat',
            disabled = true
        })
    end
    TMC.Functions.OpenMenu({
        namespace = "skillmenu",
        type = 'openMenu',
        title = "Skill menu",
    }, elements, function(close, confirmed)
    end, function(selected)
    end, function(change)
        if change.elementChanged == "stamina" then
            TMC.Functions.CloseMenu()
        elseif change.elementChanged == 'strength' then
            TMC.Functions.CloseMenu()
        end
    end)
end
```